# How do I add Python in HTML?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

Recently, I was working on my HTML project and I wanted to add some functionality and I had already written code for that in Python. But, I faced a problem I couldn't add that Python code to my HTML code.
So, I wanted to know that how I can add my Python code to my HTML code.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/ ?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, ***[search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=add+python+to+html+site%3Astackoverflow.com)***; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use PyScript it is a new framework and It uses python in HTML code to develop apps.